# Удаление первых n строк файла

Tags: cmd, powershell, zip

Этот powershell код удаляет первые 4 строки в файле

```
(gc "old.zip" | select -Skip 4) | sc "new.zip"
```

Но файл `old.zip` имеет окончание строк **Unix (LF)**

И этот код также конвертирует окончание строк файла в **Windows (CR LF)**

> Как удалить первые 4 строки без конвертирования?

Из-за наличия в **.zip** много "странных" символов 
другие способы удалить первые n строк в **.zip** файле не работают. 
Например `more +4 "old.zip" >"new.zip"` в `cmd` не работает и т.д.

Через powershell кое-как удаляется но тоже не без проблем.

> Вы знаете другие способы удалить первые n строчек в **.zip** файле?

Comment: Удаление выполняется просто - читается, что указано пропускается, остальное записывается. А при записи используется, увы, окончание строк файла а-ля Windows (CR LF)... и никаких управляющих этим делом параметров у Set-Content не наблюдается.

Comment: zip - это бинарный формат, о каких вообще строках в нем может идти речь? Если Ваша цель - получить битый zip-архив, то это можно сделать и более простыми способами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell:

```
(gc "old.txt" | select -Skip 4 | Out-String) -replace "`r`n", "`n" | Out-File "new.txt"
```

C#:

```
File.WriteAllText("new.txt", string.Join("\n", File.ReadLines("old.txt").Skip(4)));
```

Если в файле действительно текст, то и работать с ним нужно как с текстом. А если это настоящий zip-архив, то вы пытаетесь сделать что-то странное.

Comment: Спасибо, мне как раз нужен был самый короткий вариант

Answer (score -1):

I use csc.exe - c# compiler to solve this

And byte to byte copy .zip whithout first i symbols, where i is an index of text in n line.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var i = File.ReadAllText("C:\\MyFolder\\old.zip")
                .IndexOf("="+"183290132"+"=", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            var zipFolder = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\MyFolder\\old.zip")
                .Skip(i+20).ToArray();
            File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\MyFolder\\new.zip", zipFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Любопытно, почему вы вопрос задали по-русски, а ответили на него по-английски?

Comment: Я создал копию вопроса на английском stackoverflow